# python import fails when called from PHP

Tags: php, python, import, exec

I'm having a puzzling problem when trying to import a module in python only when the script is called from php via system or exec.

From the python shell:

```
import igraph #This works.
```

if the previous line was in a file, say, test_module.py, then:
python test_module.py in the bash works.

Within PHP:
exec("python test_module.py",$output,$retval) -> fails : $retval = 1.

However, if the script is instead : `import math`, then this is fine.

Anybody ever dealt with something similar?

Comment: add `import sys; print sys.path` to your script.

Comment: `import os, site; print os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'), site.USER_SITE; help(site)` might help also.

Comment: I see no differences in the sys.path within my shell or within the script called from PHP.

Comment: site.USER_SITE doesn't work for me (python2.4).
It says module object has no attribute USER_SITE.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you have installed those packages under a different user, maybe root, or something else.

How i debugged this, is i checked the output of sys.path for both cases (shell, and php's exec, which has the user www-data by default), and than i compared both.

I noticed the `'/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'` path missing when i ran it from PHP, which contained exactly these missing packages.
So i just copied the content of this folder to `'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/'`, which solved the issue.

Comment: it is a bad idea, to copy python packages by hand. You should use `apt-get`, to install Python packages to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`. Otherwise, use `pip`, to install Python packages (perhaps into a `virtualenv`). You probably don't want to run `pip` under `root` user.

Answer (score 1):

one thing to check is `sys.path`

see what the difference is when called each way

Comment: As commented above. I see no differences between the sys.path.

Answer (score 0):

Is the igraph module in Python's standard module path, or is it in the same directory as your individual script? If so, it's quite possible that PHP is calling the python file with a different working directory, and it's trying to import things relative to that path instead of the path of the script.

Comment: Within the python shell:
import igraph; print igraph.__file__ returns /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/python_igraph-0.5.2-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg/igraph/__init__.pyc

The parent directory /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/ is within the sys.path when called from the PHP script. The python_igraph-0.5.2-py2.4-linux-x86_64.egg is also within the sys.path.

Comment: Have you tried getting the output from the command (either by specifying the `output` argument for the `exec()` call, or by using `passthru()` instead) to see exactly what error python is giving when called from php?

Comment: I tried doing this. It doesn't seem to output the Python error messages so I have no idea what is going on. It does however have a return value of 1.

Comment: I redirected the error message to a file. This may help my sysadmin see what permissions I need.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the following reason.

When you import a package, certain directories are searched. These directories are specified inside sys.path

Create a python file with the following lines.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

- Run this file in the shell and note down the output(list of directory paths).
- Run the same file in the local server(using PHP) and compare the outputs.

The path missing in the PHP output is probably the one containing the package.
Therefore, add the following lines in the python file you are running on the server.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path-to-the-missing-directory")
```

RUN IT.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of failing to import self-written modules when calling Python from PHP has been treated in surprisingly many threads. Most answers deal with paths but none worked for me. Maybe trivial, but on a Linux server this was needed: **chmod o+r** to the directory that holds the scripts.