# import RPi.GPIO as GPIO not working in python when called from php

Tags: php, python, linux, raspberry-pi

i have the same problem as this question, 
[python import fails when called from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925764/python-import-fails-when-called-from-php)
but now for my another import.

The script is working from the command line (`python uit.py`) and a `test.py` whic says 'hello' also works, but when the `uit.py` (source below) is called from php, it doesn't work.
All i get is return code 1, i tried `exec(), passthru() and system(),` and none of them return anything other than '1'
I'm quite new to linux and python, so i don't know how to set the path to the import direct instead of relative (if that should help)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Hello world python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
print "Start";

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD);
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(16, True)

print "Licht uit";
```

EDIT:
What i noticed now, is that when the script from the command line, i have to `sudo` it because the script says it wants to run as `root` (i get an error when i don't run it as root saying 'maybe run as root?'.

Can that be the reason for not working? That the python script gets called from PHP as the user PHP is running under?

I did executing the statement with `sudo` (see the comments) but i've also read that maybe the php user is not allowed to `sudo`?

Comment: As mentioned in the other post: what do you get when you add `import sys; print sys.path` to your script?

Comment: this is it: ['/var/www', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']

Comment: As i'm not realy into Linux: is there a specific location where `RPi.GPIO` should be located? I installed it via `apt-get` but i don't know where binaries are stored in Linux (the equivalent of c:\program files\ in windows)

Comment: A couple of things to note.  The print statements output will go to stdout, so to collect the output form the script your php code needs to read from stdin.  (I don't know anything about php so you will need to look up how you do it.  Secondly check what version of python is being invoked by php (it may not even be running python successfully at all.)  I don't know if php honours #! in scripts, or  you will need to explicitly run python passing the script as an argument.

Comment: @Tim, the Python script is running and i'm getting the output: i have a little script called `test.py` and i can get the output in PHP. I also get the output from `print sys.path` in PHP

Comment: ok because a return code from a shell command that is not 0 normally indicates an error.  Then env variable $? is normally the return code in the shell.  So I would stick your first print statement before the imports, and one just after to make sure you are getting past the import successfully or not.

Comment: When i do this: `print 'voor import'
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
print 'na import'` then only the `voor import` line is printed.

Comment: You can see the files installed by `apt-get` with `apt-file list python-rpi.gpio`.

Comment: My raspbian Wheezy installation doesn't have a `list` option...

Comment: i see this in the messages log: imuxsock begins to drop messages from
 pid 1751 due to rate-limiting, can that have something to do with it?

Comment: I also tried running it like this:`exec('sudo /usr/bin/python3.2 "/var/www/schakel23-16-uit32.py"') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i noticed now, is that when the script from the command line, i have to sudo it because the script says it wants to run as root (i get an error when i don't run it as root saying 'maybe run as root?'.
>
> Can that be the reason for not working? That the python script gets called from PHP as the user PHP is running under?

Yes, that's your problem. The web server runs as `www-data`, not as root. (This user doesn't even have sudo access by default.) If you check the web server error log, you will probably see the "maybe run as root?" error message in there.

Comment: Hi, where can i find that log? (and next, how can i see if the www-data user has sudo rights?)

Comment: Unless you've changed things, the error log is probably in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, and `www-data` does not have sudo rights.

Comment: ah, failed to mention too, using lighttpd. Looked at those logs, nothing to see. But that could also be that there is some kind of loglevel that needs to be set before that kind of error gets logged.

Comment: hmm, weird that i never mentioned in my question that i use lighttpd in stead of apache, which is commonly used

Comment: changed the rights of the www-data user so it has sudo rights too, and it works!

Comment: @Michel I hope you only gave it rights to sudo your particular script, and made the script only writeable by root. Giving a webserver blanket sudo right is like aiming the barrel of a gun at your foot and asking people to pull the trigger for you.

Comment: @Chris: Ah, ok, thanks for the info, how can i do that, give sudo rights for only one script?

Comment: @duskwuff, you are right about rtfm, but honoustly I can not find it / do not get it.

Comment: The documentation has a number of examples. The web has more. Be resourceful.